# Why global variables are stored in .data rather than in the heap of a process image?

Tags: c, assembly, heap-memory

I was studying for a test of OS Fundamentals and this came to my mind. When I declare a global (or static) variable in a C program like:

```
char* msg = "Hello World!\n";
```

an array of bytes is reserved in the `.data` and the `"Hello World!\n"` string is saved in `.text`, then when the program is loaded to memory and starts to execute, the `msg` var is initialized with the string saved in `.text`. Is this what happens? So, what is the diference between reserving the bytes in `.data` rather than in heap? I know that in `.data` they have a static size but they cold be reserved in the heap too, right? Why are those things separated? Wouldn't it be more efficient to have just the heap, the stack and the code part in the process image rather than more fractions? It can't be because of physical memory being mapped to multiple virtual adresses (multiple instances of notepad for example) because these vars are editable.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It depends on the compiler.  These details are not specified by the language C.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: The "heap" is a run-time thing, not a compile or link time thing. Initialized global variables and string literals are a compile-/link-time thing.

Comment: i'm using gcc (don't know the version because i'm not currently in my virtual machine)

Comment: Are you saying that the bytes themselves are copied or that the variable `msg` is initialized with the *address of* the bytes in .data? (I can't reproduce your example; I suggest that you compile a minimal program with the `-S` option so that you can see the generated code; if you require clarification, post both the program and the generated code (my attempt produced 32 lines of generated code, which is still within reason for a question here.)

Comment: `data` only deserves space for a pointer, the `"Hello, world!"` string continues to be in the .text segment and nothing is copied anywhere.  the `msg` variable (a pointer stored in `.data` segment) is only a pointer to the place in `.text` segment where the character array resides (read only). Just try to modify something with `msg[3] = '\0';` and see how it fails (despite of `msg` being a `char *` and not a `const char *`)

Answer (score 1):

What this compiler does, is make this (constant) literal a read/write variable.

The compiler collects in `.text` all literal strings. When a literal string is used more than once in the program, it will use only one occurrence of the literal in `.text`.

At startup, it copies it to the reserved space in `.data`. This is funny:

```
char msg[] = "Hello World!\n";
char *msg  = "Hello World!\n";
```

That the compiler copies the first literal from `.text` to `.data` is OK; it is initializing the variable as per the user's instructions.

That the compiler copies the second literal to `.data` is not correct: it should have initialized `*msg` wih a pointer to the literal in `.text` and the `.text` segment should be made read-only (managed by the memory hardware, causing an exception when the memory is attempted to be written to).

Answer (score 1):

"Global" generally means "accessible from everywhere".

Generally one does that in assembler by placing the global data in a fixed location; then any code needing access simply references it directly by using its address.   That is accomplished by placing global variables in the the .data segment; the linker will assign them fixed addresses.

You can consider placing "global data" in the heap.  If you do that, how does code access it?   It can't, without knowing where the data is in the heap.  The only way for such code to know this is either be passed a pointer to the "global data" as an argument (that means *every subroutine* has to accept this pointer and pass it to all callees; that's really inconvenient), or code has to know where there is pointer into the heap that the code can access directly (that pointer would have to have a fixed address to be found, so the pointer itself is global data).    Having such a pointer means that access to global data now always requires an indirection, which slows the code down.   So, if you do this, you end up with an awkward and slow scheme for accessing "global" data.  (Most people wouldn't call data allocated in the heap "global data").

So... global data is placed where it is easy to access.  In the data segment.

If you have global data which is constant and will not change, you can put it in the "text" (code) segment.  Putting such data in a text segment ensures, with most modern OSes, that such data is write protected, enforcing the "won't change" assumption.   That helps find bugs in programs.

Comment: "_It can't_" is absolutely incorrect: `.heap` is just a segment. After these (fixed) variables follows the heap as you traditionally know it: managed by `malloc` etc. "_the linker will assign them fixed addresses_" is also incorrect: the loader does that. I downvoted your solution because of this.

Comment: "_Putting such data in a text segment ensures ... such data is write protected_" is the point: after copying the literals to `.data`, these data are no longer write-protected.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I bow to your knowledge that there *can be* or *is* a ".heap" segment (I assume in fact I can name segments arbitrarily), but OP ask about "the heap" so I think my answer reflects his question properly.   Yes, the loader assigns the final addresses in many systems, I stand corrected.

Comment: Well, he talks about segments, so obviously means a heap segment.

Comment: Where did he say *segment*?

Comment: What you think he means with `.text` and `.data`?

Comment: I think he means "linker/loader" concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the `text` and `data` areas are *initialized* by the loader. Heap storage for C programs is (normally) what's returned by `malloc()` and its kin. It isn't *uninitialized* and provided by by the OS as needed, not at program load time. That's why it's also called dynamic storage.

Literal constants like your string *are* initialized by copying information from the compiled binary into storage allocated by the OS to the loader. The segment names you gave `.text` and `.data` are conventions used in compiled binary files to label such information. The different flavors tell the OS how the copies should be mapped in the VM space - as read-only, read-write, etc.

All I've said above is merely typical. The compiler decides how to store C values in the memory model provided by the OS and hardware. Your questions and prospective answers are only relevant to the compiler and OS you're using.

The line

```
char* msg = "Hello World!\n";
```

declaring an initialized global `char` pointer value can be compiled in many ways. But the most commonsense is to allocate a literal string `Hello World~\n\0` in read-only storage (Linux `.text`). C allows but does not require the literal string to be protected so that code like

```
char* msg = "Hello World!\n";

...
{
  ...
  char *p = msg;
  strcpy(msg, "foo"); 
  printf("%s", p);
```

will raise an error (often a segment violation) rather than printing `foo`. Not all OS/compiler configs will do this. For example, an embedded system might not support read-only storage, so the above code might run, though after it does, the C standard doesn't specify anything about what the program will do afteward.

The other thing the compiler needs to do is allocate and initialize the global value of `msg`. This is (normally) a 2-, 4- or 8-byte pointer, again depending on compiler, OS, and hardware. It must be set to the address of the literal string. The commonsense way to do this is emit symbols into the binary that allow the loader to take care the initialization in read-write storage (Linux `.data`) as the program is starting. But there are other other options: fixed offsets and startup code are two.

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of initialization of objects with static storage duration (SSD) that is performed at run-time is what is commonly referred as *dynamic* initialization (to borrow a C++ term). Dynamic initialization of SSD objects, however useful it might be, brings about a number of problems. For example, the final outcome of such initialization might depend on the order in which it is performed. The initialization might fail for some unpredictable reason (out of memory?). And, obviously, the values of SSD objects cannot be treated as constant expressions.

Meanwhile, in order to steer clear of such issues C language specification was consciously designed to avoid any need for dynamic initialization for SSD objects. For example, all such objects in C program are required to be initialized with constant values. Which means that the initial values of such objects are free from any initialization order dependencies and are conceptually "known at compile time". When a C program starts, all SSD  objects begin their lives with properly pre-assigned values, requiring no extra run-time initialization.

However, the reality is more complicated and it is not always possible to predict initial values of SSD objects at compile time. For example, address constants that describe locations of relocatable objects become known only at loading time, not at compile time, which generally makes it impossible to predict the values of SSD pointers at compile-time. The language specification is designed to accommodate such peculiarities. Properties of address constants in C are deliberately restricted to make it possible to initialize their values later, at *loading* time. In C this is considered a proper compromise in situation when the initial value is not known at compile time, and yet we still want to maintain the appearance of SSD objects beginning their lives in pre-initialized state.

Note that the language specification does not require it to be implemented in that fashion specifically. It says

> All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to
>   their initial values) before program startup. The manner and timing of
>   such initialization are otherwise unspecified.

This means that it is probably quite possible to come up with a valid implementation that will use heap memory to allocate storage for SSD objects and meet all other requirements of language specification. But historically C implementation typically strived to avoid run-time initialization and preferred to rely on initialized data segment (like `.data`) and some basic loader features. Again, the language specification is deliberately tailored to this approach to SSD object support.

Answer (score 0):

`.data` only deserves space for a pointer (the pointer variable `msg`), the `"Hello, world!"` string continues to be in the `.text` segment and nothing is copied anywhere.  the `msg` variable (a pointer stored in `.data` segment) is only a pointer to the place in `.text` segment where the character array resides (being that array read only). Just try to modify something in the array with, for example, `msg[3] = '\0';` and see how it fails (despite of `msg` being a `char *` and not a `const char *`)